# Create identical timestamp for each n elements

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, timestamp

I have a function which creates an artificial list of 100.000 timestamps going back in time. The frequency is 2 minutes.

`datelist = pd.date_range(end = pd.datetime.today(), periods=100000, freq='2min00S').tolist()`

The result looks like:

```
[Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:48:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:50:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:52:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:54:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:56:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 19:58:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 20:00:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 20:02:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 20:04:35.874707', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-03 20:06:35.874707', freq='2T'),
...]
```

I would like to create an identical timestamp for each 50 elements. 
At the moment I have a different timestamp for each 100.000 elements. Any idea to do that?

In other words: The frequency of 2 minutes remains the same but the timestamp will be identical for each 50 elements.

This final list will be integrated as new column into a pandas dataframe.

`data_pd['Timestamp'] = datelist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need indexing `DatetimeIndex` after removed `tolist()` by array with integer division of `50` by `numpy.arange` by lenght of DataFrame:

```
dates = pd.date_range(end = pd.datetime.today(), periods=100000, freq='2min00S')
data_pd['Timestamp'] = dates[np.arange(len(data_pd)) // 50]
```

**Sample**: (each 5 values)

```
dates = pd.date_range(end = pd.datetime.today(), periods=100000, freq='2min00S')
data_pd = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})
data_pd['Timestamp'] = dates[np.arange(len(data_pd)) // 5]

print (data_pd)
   a                  Timestamp
0  0 2019-08-17 13:20:41.002125
1  1 2019-08-17 13:20:41.002125
2  2 2019-08-17 13:20:41.002125
3  3 2019-08-17 13:20:41.002125
4  4 2019-08-17 13:20:41.002125
5  5 2019-08-17 13:22:41.002125
6  6 2019-08-17 13:22:41.002125
7  7 2019-08-17 13:22:41.002125
8  8 2019-08-17 13:22:41.002125
9  9 2019-08-17 13:22:41.002125
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Very well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
end_time = pd.datetime.today()
end_date = end_time.date()
datelist = pd.date_range(end = end_date, periods=100000, freq='2min00S').tolist()
```

convert the end_time to date instead of using a time with decimal seconds. This will always gives you the same time

```
[Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:42:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:44:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:46:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:48:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:50:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:52:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:54:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:56:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 02:58:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 03:00:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 03:02:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 03:04:00', freq='2T'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-17 03:06:00', freq='2T'),
```